# What causes Jenkins Workflow Unknown Steps / Tasks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Running Jenkins Workflow version 1.10, I have noticed that sometimes the Build queue will show jobs queued with a display name of **part of unknown step**, or an executor will be executing something called **Unknown Task**

These tasks can't be cancelled.  I'm curious what these unknown tasks / steps signify and how a workflow step gets into this state and finally if they can be prevented.  I did try searching the Internet and the workflow plugin documentation, but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there is a bug. 1.11 makes it possible to cancel these when they occur. The root causes continue to be investigated as they are reproduced.

Comment: By the way in 1.13 I made an improvement ([103b73b](https://github.com/jglick/workflow-plugin/commit/103b73b1923dec3cd16a530fdbb552f58ffefb4b) amended by [3af788c](https://github.com/jglick/workflow-plugin/commit/3af788cbdf30da84665502998e72b7c06b7b36f5)) which should show the actual job name and build number in most cases. Noticed that when Jenkins was restarted during a build inside `node`, and the slave was slow to reconnect, the pending `node` resumption task was not properly labeled.